# Windows 2003 R2 Server out of Memory each 3 days

Tags: mysql, iis, memory, windows-server-2003-r2

I am having a 2003 R2 Server with IIS and mysql running. My problem is, that the server stops responding on the net each 3 days. When I log on I get an error, that I can't log on (0x000012d) 
The only thing I can do: restart

All logs are clean. Nothing special in the log. I can see only services logging that no memory is available.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the master browser errors are directly related to the problem. Run perfmon and check the Memory|Pool Nonpaged Bytes counter. The following articles relate to IIS on an Exchange server but they are related to IIS problems when the Memory|Pool Nonpaged Bytes usage is too high (pool exhaustion). I couldn't find the articles specific to IIS but these should help:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/mikelag/archive/2009/09/15/how-to-monitor-and-troubleshoot-the-use-of-nonpaged-pool-memory-in-exchange-server-2003-or-in-exchange-2000-server.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/03/26/3211216.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/?id=934878

Answer (score 0):

For what   you using this server  what  you have there ?  how many ram  have and swap ?  What  is writing  on logs ?

Comment: logs are clean - nothing special in.

Comment: 4 Gig RAM - standard SWAP from Windows

Comment: All i can see is, that first an event "master browser not found" appears. After that it takes about 20 Minutes an the System is unusable. I think that log entry is in advance of the unavailable RAM. We logged the memory usage (paging) with perfmon. 10 minutes before the crash no more pages a processed. Perfmom shows no more action with paged memory. Than the system dies ...